# Creating custom data attribute for Sitecore form fields

Tags: sitecore-forms

How to implement html data attribute for Sitecore forms? For example in the styling section, I would like to add custom input for data attribute.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Is this helpful https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/91/sitecore-experience-management/en/walkthrough--creating-a-custom-form-element.html ?

Comment: Hi Marek, I am not looking for adding form element, want to add input field for data attribute inside styling section like css class.

Comment: Yes, but in the article you can find instructions how to add styling fields

Comment: I have followed the same steps which you have mentioned above in creating custom data attributes. But i was always getting error, below is the exception which i captured from logs: Exception: "CustomDataAttribute.CustomSingleLineViewModel' does not contain a definition for 'CustomDataAttribute' and no extension method 'CustomDataAttribute' accepting a first argument of type 'CustomDataAttribute.CustomSingleLineViewModel' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)" In the above "CustomDataAttribute" is the Namespace and "CustomSingleLineViewModel" is the class.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

For your requirement you can either create new `Single-line text` field or you can update in existing `Single-line text` field. I am focusing on existing one. Below are the steps:

1. Move to the location `/sitecore/templates/System/Forms/Fields/Field` and add `CustomAttribute` field with `Single-Line Text`

[image]

2. Switch to `Core` db and go to this location `/sitecore/client/Applications/FormsBuilder/Components/Layouts/PropertyGridForm/PageSettings/Common/Styling`
3. Create duplication item of `CssClass` and rename it with `CustomAttribute`
4. Update `FormLabel` to `Custom Attribute`
5. Add `BindingConfiguration` to `customAttribute`

   [image]
6. Now create new custom view model `CustomSingleLineViewModel` in your code

```
 [Serializable()]
    public class CustomSingleLineViewModel : StringInputViewModel
    {
        public string CustomAttribute { get; set; }
        protected override void InitItemProperties(Item item)
        {
            base.InitItemProperties(item);
            CustomAttribute = StringUtil.GetString(item.Fields["CustomAttribute"]);
        }
        protected override void UpdateItemFields(Item item)
        {
            base.UpdateItemFields(item);
            item.Fields["CustomAttribute"]?.SetValue(CustomAttribute,true);
        }
    }
```

7. Now go to this location `Views\FormBuilder\FieldTemplates` and open `SingleLineText.cshtml`
8. Update cshtml code and replace namespace

```
@using Sitecore.ExperienceForms.Mvc.Html
@model Sitecore.Foundation.Forms.Fields.CustomSingleLineViewModel

<label for="@Html.IdFor(m => Model.Value)" class="@Model.LabelCssClass custom-form__label" custom-attribute="@Model.CustomAttribute">@Html.DisplayTextFor(t => Model.Title)</label>
<input id="@Html.IdFor(m => Model.Value)" name="@Html.NameFor(m => Model.Value)" class="@Model.CssClass form-control form-control__primary" type="text" value="@Model.Value" @if (Model.MaxLength > 0) { <text> maxlength="@Model.MaxLength" </text> } placeholder="@Model.PlaceholderText" data-sc-tracking="@Model.IsTrackingEnabled" data-sc-field-name="@Model.Name" @Html.GenerateUnobtrusiveValidationAttributes(m => m.Value) />
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => Model.Value)
```

9. In master db, move into this location `/sitecore/system/Settings/Forms/Field Types/Basic/Single-Line Text`  and update `Model Type` with new viewmodel

[image]

10. Go to Form explorer and create new form and drag `Single-line text`
11. Now you can see `Custom Attribute` field

[image]
[image]

More information you can check here https://www.codinglittlethings.com/2019/07/custom-data-attribute-for-sitecore-form-field.html

Comment: Thank you Swati Gupta :)

Comment: Great post Swati. One question, won’t Sitecore items get override after upgrade?

Answer (score 5):

I followed Swati Gupta's answer using Sitecore 10.2 and found these additional steps were needed.

After duplicating the `CssClass` item and renaming it to `CustomAttribute`. Change its `RenderingItemId` from
`sitecore/client/Applications/FormsBuilder/Components/Layouts/Renderings/TagEditor` to `sitecore/client/Business Component Library/version 2/Layouts/Renderings/Common/TextBox`.

Then, still in Core DB go to
`/sitecore/client/Applications/FormsBuilder/Components/Layouts/PropertyGridForm/PageSettings/Settings/SingleLineText/Styling`

Here add `CustomAttribute` to the `ControlDefinitions` from `/sitecore/client/Applications/FormsBuilder/Components/Layouts/PropertyGridForm/PageSettings/Common/Styling/CustomAttribute`.

(I am aware you are not meant to use answers to respond to another answer, but I do not have enough reputation to add a comment.)