# Can we add aria-describedby attribute on a Sitecore Form?

Tags: sitecore-forms

Following the best pratices https://www.w3.org/WAI/tutorials/forms/instructions/ I was wondering if we can add `aria-describedby` on a given input of a Sitecore Form?

Comment: Is this something you are looking for - https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/18641/creating-custom-data-attribute-for-sitecore-form-fields ?

Comment: Thanks, I think that answers my question. There is no OOTB thing for that so a custom field is the only way.