# Sitecore Forms Custom Attribute Not Working in Designer Mode

Tags: sitecore-forms, custom-field

I have created custom attributes on standard fields by following instructions in this post:
[Creating custom data attribute for Sitecore form fields](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/18641/creating-custom-data-attribute-for-sitecore-form-fields)
E.g., Single line input, multi line input etc. I can populate them when in the content tree just fine:
[image]

And it renders the values on the page as you can see:
[image]

Problem is, when in forms designer mode, the values that I have entered in the content tree mode for my custom attributes dont get populated. If I manually re-enter them here and hit apply, they get cleared out.
[image]

Any idea what is going on? Did I miss a setting somewhere? Here is the model:

```
using System;
using Sitecore.Data.Items;
using Sitecore.ExperienceForms.Mvc.Models.Fields;
using Sitecore;
namespace Helix.Foundation.Forms.Fields
{
    [Serializable()]
    public class CustomSingleLineViewModel : StringInputViewModel
    {
        public string AriaLabel { get; set; }
        public string AriaRequired { get; set; }
        public string AutoComplete { get; set; }
        protected override void InitItemProperties(Item item)
        {
            base.InitItemProperties(item);
            AriaLabel = StringUtil.GetString(item.Fields["aria-label"]);
            AriaRequired = StringUtil.GetString(item.Fields["aria- 
required"]);
            AutoComplete = StringUtil.GetString(item.Fields["autocomplete"]);
        }
         protected override void UpdateItemFields(Item item)
        {
            base.UpdateItemFields(item);
             item.Fields["aria-label"]?.SetValue(AriaLabel, true);
             item.Fields["aria-required"]?.SetValue(AriaRequired, true);
            item.Fields["autocomplete"]?.SetValue(AutoComplete, true);
         }
     }
 }

@using Sitecore.ExperienceForms.Mvc.Html
@model Helix.Foundation.Forms.Fields.CustomSingleLineViewModel

<input id="@Html.IdFor(m => Model.Value)" aria-label="@Model.AriaLabel" aria- 
required="@Model.AriaRequired" autocomplete="@Model.AutoComplete" 
name="@Html.NameFor(m => Model.Value)" class="@Model.CssClass" type="text" 
value="@Model.Value" @if (Model.MaxLength > 0) { <text> 
maxlength="@Model.MaxLength" </text> } placeholder="@Model.PlaceholderText" 
data-sc-tracking="@Model.IsTrackingEnabled" data-sc-field-name="@Model.Name" 
data-sc-field-key="@Model.ConditionSettings.FieldKey" 
@Html.GenerateUnobtrusiveValidationAttributes(m => m.Value) />
<label for="@Html.IdFor(m => Model.Value)" 
class="@Model.LabelCssClass">@Html.DisplayTextFor(t => Model.Title)</label>
<div>
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => Model.Value, "", new { @class = "sc-form- 
   validation" })
</div>
```

Comment: Could you please add code as well, which you have done?

Comment: @SwatiGupta. Model and view added.

Answer (score 1):

I was also facing the same issue. In core DB, property editor settings - binding configuration, the model property should be in camel case. Once I added the model property in camel case, the issue was fixed.
In you case, ariaLabel, ariaRequired etc

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try to add autocomplete value in code db like below:

[image]

Comment: Yes. I already have autocomplete there.