# How to add custom attribute to Sitecore Form Submit Button?

Tags: sitecore-forms

I want to add a custom attribute to Sitecore form submit button like `custom-attribute="@value"`.

Here is an example I found which shows how to add for other fields, but the same I cannot replicate for submit button:
[Creating custom data attribute for Sitecore form fields](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/18641/creating-custom-data-attribute-for-sitecore-form-fields)

Which View file to be changed? where to do the change in core dB to add custom attribute in submit button?

Answer (score 1):

1. You can find a view in this location `C:\inetpub\wwwroot\XXX\Views\FormBuilder\FieldTemplates` and this view you can add in your code:

[image]

- Below are the changes for core db as mentioned in link:

```
 - Switch to Core db and go to this location /sitecore/client/Applications/FormsBuilder/Components/Layouts/PropertyGridForm/PageSettings/Common/Styling
 - Create duplication item of CssClass and rename it with CustomAttribute
 - Update FormLabel to Custom Attribute
 - Add BindingConfiguration to customAttribute
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Which view has to be changed?

   `[YOUR_WEBSITE]\Views\FormBuilder\FieldTemplates\Button.cshtml`
2. where to do the change in core dB to add custom attribute in submit button?

   You can find it here: `/sitecore/client/Applications/FormsBuilder/Components/Layouts/PropertyGridForm/PageSettings/Settings/Button`